# Unexpected T_STRING error in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm using `Codeigniter 2.2`. 
I'm trying to build a table using HTML table class library. It also contain the delete button with it .for the button purpose I m using form_button() helper .view file of my code is as below :

```
<?php
foreach($invoices as $row) {
    $data = array(
        'type' => 'button',
        'content' => 'delete',
        'class'=>'btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle',
    );

    $js='onclick="confirm_modal('base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id']')"';
    $links  = form_button($data,$js);

    $this->table->add_row(
        $this->crud_model->get_type_name_by_id('student',$row['student_id']),$row['title'],$row['description'],$row['amount'],$row['amount_paid'],$row['due'],$row['status'] ,$links 
        );

    }
    echo $this->table->generate();
     ?>
```

But in the row :

```
$js='onclick="confirm_modal('base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id']')"';
```

I am getting error as

> unexpected T_ STRING.

Please help me out....thanx in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error

```
 $js='onclick="confirm_modal('base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id']')"';
```

missing the `.` (s)

```
$js='onclick="confirm_modal(\''.base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id'].'\')"';
```

A good IDE will help you avoid these simple mistakes.

The `T_STRING` is the name of a STRING token used when PHP interprets your text into code, AKA the lexer/parser part of the deal.  So an UNEXPECTED T_STRING is an unexpected string meaning a string that is just chilling where it's not meant to be.

And based on another comment your also missing the `'` for the JS part.

Another way to do it would be a HEREDOC

```
 $url = base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id'];

 $js= <<<SCRIPT
 onclick="confirm_modal('{$url}')"
 SCRIPT; //nothing can go here no spaces not even this comment.
```

With a HEREDOC you can use both quotes freely, but you can't put function calls in them.  You have to be careful with the ending TAG (you can use whatever you want for the tag) but the ending tag has to be on it's own line with nothing else not even a single space.

I forget if going to the next line puts a line return in there, it looks better anyway.  HEREDOCs can take a bit of getting used to but they can really free up the quotes and make things a bit simpler overall when dealing with putting in multiple types of quotes.

Comment: ...and `confirm_modal(' . base_url().'admin/`.. .

Comment: UPDATED! thanks, I missed that one.

Comment: Sure it was pretty simple, as these things go

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong concat 
it should be like

```
$js='onclick="confirm_modal('.base_url().'admin/invoice/delete/'. $row['invoice_id'].')"';
```